# Generating random id using current date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm doing a bank oriented project. I have to generate Account Number using current date.

Example:

`account no-20150409001`. 
`'2015'-Year`, 
`'04'-Month`, 
`'09'-Date`, 
`'001'`-represents the number of the new member opening the account on that particular date

This number should change in every branch to avoid same account number.

How to do so?

and this is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/Jegannath/z9na41o5/#&togetherjs=ynHxlyDeO1

Comment: Simply add branch code as prefix of account number like 1223-20150409001 OR 122320150409001 where 1223 is branch number.

Comment: please provide code of what did you try

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=ynHxlyDeO1

Comment: Use timestamp to use instead of date

Comment: use PHP or Javascript ? how does this relate to PDO ? Don't add unrelated tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is really a bank related project, do not rely on client side JavaScript for something as critical as the account number generation.

Is there a reason for the "random" number requirement? If not, stick with a sequence, it is a lot easier to ensure uniqueness.

On the server side, using a branch prefix as suggested by @kuldeep.kamboj should cover collision.

You can use something like yyyyMMddBBnnnn where yyyy = year, MM = month, dd = day, BB = branch number, and nnnn as a sequence that resets per day.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure,this is correct advise,

Go with branch code prefix and timestamp in suffix, this might be developer friend also, because in future after 30 year easily you can tell his account created date with the help of timestamp.

As well timestamps is kind of random number.

advisable is server side code.